# Running virtual machines on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server-2008

The Server Core installation option for the Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 operating system provides a minimal environment for running specific server. I want to run a minimal linux build  Virtual machine on this installation. Is it possible? Can i use a Vmware virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your questions first:

**Q)** Is it possible to run GNU/Linux virtual machine on server core
**A)** Yes with HyperV role

**Q)** Can I use a VMWare Virtual Machine
**A)** No. There is limited capabilities for the Server Core UI.

You could enable the Hyper-V role on your server. If you have a Vista or Win 7 machine you can also download the HyperV management tools to assist in creating your virtual machines.

Try these sites for help:

- [How To Install Hyper V RTM On Server Core](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2008/07/09/how-to-install-hyper-v-rtm-on-server-core.aspx)
- [Installing Hyper V On Windows Server 2008 Server Core](http://www.petri.co.il/installing-hyper-v-on-windows-server-2008-server-core.htm)
- [Hyper V On Server Core](http://blogs.technet.com/tonyso/archive/2008/07/16/hyper-v-on-server-core.aspx)